# For real numbers $x>1,y>1$, define $P,Q$ as $P= \ln \sqrt {xy},Q= \sqrt {\ln x \ln y}$.

Tags: real-analysis

> For real numbers $x>1,y>1$, define $P,Q$ as  $P= \ln \sqrt {xy},Q= \sqrt {\ln x \ln y}$. 
>   Which of the following is true for $x>1,y>1$ ?
>
> 1. $P \geq Q$
> 2. $P \leq Q$
> 3. $P=Q$
> 4. There is no relation between $P,Q.$

My Attempt:  $P=\frac {1}{2} (\ln x+ \ln y)=\frac {1}{2} (a+b)$ and $Q=\sqrt {ab}$ [Where $a= \ln x,b=\ln y$] Now, A.M. $ \geq $ G.M. gives $\frac {1}{2} (a+b) \geq \sqrt {ab} \implies  P \geq Q.$  <s>But from here, no such conclusion can be made as here both   x,y >1</s>  . So, (1) is the correct option. Am I right ?

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You don't have to compare $x, y$. Seems to me you have enough to compare $P, Q$, which is what is asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's correct. But you might want to add something about $x\gt1$ and $y\gt1$ leading to $a\gt0$ and $b\gt0$ because that relation holds for $ab\ge 0$.